# Encrypt XOR in Delphi / Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, delphi, base64, xor

Ok guys, few days ago I translated my simple XOR function in Delphi for PHP and it was working fine. Today when I tried again for some unknown reason, it's broken. What I'm doing is: first I do a base64 encode in the string, then I xor it. So I send it for PHP over POST method, and in PHP I 'unxor' and decode base64. Look the function in Delphi(i'm using EncodeBase64 from EncdDecd unit):

```
function EncryptStr(Input: AnsiString; Seed: integer): AnsiString;
var
i : integer;
Output : AnsiString;
begin
    Input:= EncodeBase64(BytesOf(UTF8Encode(Input)),  Length(BytesOf(UTF8Encode(Input))));
    Output := '';
    for i := 1 to Length(Input) do
        Output := Output + AnsiChar(Ord(Input[i]) XOR (Seed));
    Result:= Output;
end;
```

Ok, so I send this way over Indy HTTP(don't know if this matters, but can be useful)

```
procedure TForm1.DoPost;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lPost: TStringList;
begin
  Http:= TIDHttp.Create(nil);
  lPost:= TStringList.Create;
  Http.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)';
  lPost.Add('PNAME=' + EncryptStr('test.exe', 232));
  lPost.Add('BYTETYPE=' + EncryptStr('UNICODE', 232));
  Http.Post('http://192.168.1.12/panel.php?uid=09ed-erty-as98-1498', lPost);
```

In PHP I receive/decrypt in this way:

```
 function DecryptStr($str)
  {
    $key = '232'; //key need to be the same as hook is using!
    $strsize = @strlen($str);   
    $j = @strlen($key);
    for($i=$strsize-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
     {
       $str[$i] = @chr(@ord($str[$i]) ^ $key);
     }
     $str = base64_decode($str);
     return $str;
    }

 if(isset($_POST['PNAME']) && isset($_POST['BYTETYPE']) && ($_POST['BYTETYPE'] != ''))
  {
    saveInfo($uid, DecryptStr($_POST['PNAME']), DecryptStr($_POST['BYTETYPE']), $con); 
  }
```

The saveInfo function is just doing some echo in the variables decrypted, but I get everything corrupted... What's wrong?

Comment: Do XOR in Delphi create http-friendly characters, "us-ascii", to be used in lPost parameter list? Is http post charset UTF8 or ISO* and receiving end PHP script uses the same charset decoding bytes to post envvars?

Comment: Yeah, he should base64 AFTER xoring

Comment: I don't think the problem is in Http.Post or TStringList... Even when I do in the PHP: `$decrypt = 'œš‰‹ƒ'; (pass encrypted xor value directly)
DecryptStr($decrypt); ` 
I still getting corrupted value. Don't know why, I checked this days ago and worked, now only corrupted... And I tried to base64 after xor, but since xor is corrupted, didn't worked.

Comment: Just a small correction on your terminology: You're not encrypting/decrypting; you're encoding/decoding. Encoding & Decoding refers to a general change in the form of your data. Encryption & Decryption is a *special kind* of encoding/decoding with the specific goal of **protecting** your data by making it "cryptic". In that way it will be hard for someone whose not allowed access to your data change it back and use it. I only mention this because if you really want to ***encrypt*** (protect) your data, then Base64 is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the UTF8 encoding. I changed it to first XOR after XOR I do Base64. And in Base64 in delphi I did:

> Input:= EncodeBase64(BytesOf(Input), 
>   Length(BytesOf(Input)));

Instead of:

> Input:= EncodeBase64(BytesOf(UTF8Encode(Input)), 
>   Length(BytesOf(UTF8Encode(Input))));

Removing the UTF8Encode it was correctly decrypted in PHP.